# Regex issue - Matcher taking so much to time to match.

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to process source file which contains below line, file contains more than 100 columns and it is tab delimited file.

```
private static Matcher FILE_NAME_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\d(F|G|H|J|K|M|N|Q|U|V|X|Z)\t169\t3(.*\t){26}\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");

    String line = "CGAS0Z   169 3   38977.5 02:30:00    -350    76000   75700   2255        76000   76000   76000       588             2                               76000   06:35:15    2013/03/04                  2013/03/05  02:17:40    CGAS    1   JPY CHUKYO Gasoline                 Futures CHUKYO Gasoline CONT (CGAS3H)           JP      FUD         169                         RES     XTKT    2013/03/05  2013/03/05  2013/03/05          10  76350                                       10                                  81950   61500       4296057 19178.8258928571    224 CGAS        2013/03/25  116.3987300506  0.5196371877        75700   2255                    0.7841672   8.582539    23.298309           12.458333";

    if (FILE_NAME_REGEX.reset(line).matches()) {
        System.out.println(":)");
    } else {
        System.out.println(":(");
    }
```

When I am testing this code then it is taking hell lot of time. Can someone please explain whats wrong with this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve via this regex? In Java, the regex should be "^\\w+\\d(F|G|H|J|K|M|N|Q|U|V|X|Z)\\t169\\t3(.\\t){26}\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}.". You need to use "\\" instead of "\".

Comment: Basically I need to use it in my spring project.

  <property name="dataRegexList"> 
      <list>
       <value>^\w+\d(F|G|H|J|K|M|N|Q|U|V|X|Z)\t169\t3\t(.+\t){25}\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}.+</value>
      </list>
  </property>

There are millions of line in source file, out of which I am interested in contracts which ends with (F|G|H|J|K|M|N|Q|U|V|X|Z) and contract name should be 169 and type should be 3. In some of the line date comes empty then I want to skip this line. and I want regex to achieve it.

Comment: @lhuang - *usually* both work: there can be a literal tab in the string: `"\t"`, or a literal slash and a t: `"\\t"`. In both cases the pattern parser gets a tab. Still, you are right, it is usually better to use `"\\t"` - it protects you from "ignore spaces" mode (`/x`, or expanded).

Comment: You may want to use `[FGHJKMNQUVXZ]` instead of `(F|G|H|J|K|M|N|Q|U|V|X|Z)`.

Comment: @Kobi: I think he was talking about all the *other* backslashes, which were correctly doubled but were showing up as singles because the OP didn't format the code properly.  That's a good point about `"\\t"` though.  I copied the (now correctly formatted) regex string and pasted it into RegexBuddy using its *Paste from Java String* function, and all the `\t`'s dropped out.  I didn't know what was happening until I read your comment.  Turns out Free-spacing mode was still selected from my last session.  So cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I'd try it like this:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\d[FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\t169\t3([^\t]*\t){26}\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

`([^\t]*\t){26}` should be much quicker than `(.*\t){26}`, because it only has one way to match the text. This can also be adapted to support tabs in quoted values, if needed.

Also, you will want to use the `(?m)` or `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag  if you want `^` to work as expected when searching a whole file, and not just a single line.

Comment: Thanks a ton kobi! It works like charm! God bless you! :) Thank you all others who took their time out to help! Appreciated :)

Comment: This is called catastrophic backtracking, and explained in details here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html